# Odd redirect to localhost instead of ip with node / express

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I try to run a node server together with nginx. With passport modul I follow the local authentication strategy. My problem is that all express redirects like '/login' lead to 'localhost:3000/login' instead 'http://:3000/login'.

That an example function:

```
exports.ensureAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Even res.redirect(server+'/login') makes no difference when server is the remote ip plus port.

Here is my nginx configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default)

```
upstream node_app {
    server **<ip>**:3000;
}

server {

  listen 8080;
  server_name **<ip>**;

  root /home/nls/www2;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/foo.access.log;
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  location /remote_data/ {

    # Proxy request to node:

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://node_app;
    proxy_redirect off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/foo_nodeapp.access.log;

  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html 404;
  }

}
```

The server code contains no reference to localhost redirects. Also on client side is redirect implemented without such redirects.

**Edit:** This the rout which makes trouble:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: 'http://<ip>:3000/login', failureFlash: true }), function(req, res) { res.redirect('http://**<ip>**:3000/vi-lab'); });
```

Comment: The Server should listen to 8080 but in fact its 3000. I do not mind what port it is so far.

Comment: So no answers are also an answer.